# Postar uma frase predefinida no Twitter

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-api

```
const frase = 'Olá Mundo!'

<a href="https://twitter.com/compose/tweet" target='_blank'>
    <button>Twitter</button>
```

O link da tag `<a>` redireciona para a página do Twitter já com o 'What's happening?' aberto, para o usuário fazer uma publicação.
Existe alguma maneira desse link carregar a frase definida anteriormente, fazendo com que o usuário não precise digitar 'Olá Mundo!'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se faz sentido pra o que você quer fazer, mas é possível passar o parâmetro `text` para a URL que você está usando.

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/compose/tweet?text=Olá Mundo" target='_blank'> 
    Tweetar 'Olá Mundo'
</a>
```

#### Como alterar o valor do `href` em tempo de execução?

Você pode alterar qualquer coisa (ou praticamente) da sua página web usando JavaScript. No seu caso, é preciso seguir estes 2 passos simples:

1. Obter o elemento `a` da página usando algum API para isto - `document.getElementById`, `document.querySelector` e assim por diante...
2. Alterar a propriedade `href` deste elemento para o valor que a variável contém.

Exemplo:

```js
const urlBase = "https://twitter.com/compose/tweet"
const texto = "Meu tweet"

var btn = document.querySelector('#btn-tweet');

btn.addEventListener('click', () =>
{
  const elementoAncora = document.querySelector('a')
  elementoAncora.href = `${urlBase}?text=${texto}`
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-tweet">Alterar texto do tweet</button>
<br>
<a href="https://twitter.com/compose/tweet?text=Olá Mundo" target='_blank'> 
    Tweetar
</a>
```

Para o código ficar útil mesmo você vai precisar obter este texto de algum lugar, mas isso fica de tarefa *=)*

Comment: É quase isso, mas desse jeito sempre vai ser publicado 'Olá Mundo'. Caso a variável mude, o link ainda ira carregar a mensagem de 'Olá Mundo', e não o conteúdo da variável.

Comment: @GuilhermeArruda Ok, mas você é programador, né? Agora é só usar suas habilidades pra alterar o valor do `href`. Minha contribuição foi te informar do parâmetro `text` _=)_

Comment: Sou um estudante, estou tentando tirar uma dúvida, ainda não sei alterar o `href` para que faça o que estou buscando. Se puder deixar algum artigo que possa ser útil eu agradeceria.

Comment: @GuilhermeArruda Tá certo, tentei mostrar pra você na resposta o que precisa ser feito para usar o valor da variável na URL, espero que tenha ficado claro xD

Comment: Obrigado, consegui entender melhor agora. Ficou mais fácil pra adaptar também da forma que eu preciso. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: @GuilhermeArruda Tranquilo, jovem. Boa sorte nos seus estudos =D